# Visual Studio c# winform opening a link

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, hyperlink

I wanted to open link from my c# application. I saw many people
writing this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.example.com");
```

but everything this code does for me is just stopping the program
and displays error that says the system can't find this file.

Please help me :(

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default, the process is started with [`UseShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) set to `false`, which means that the process can only run executable files (such as `.exe` files).

Instead, specific `UseShellExecute = true` to allow the OS to determine how to launch the process, as per the following example:

```
Process newProcess = new Process();
newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "https://www.example.com";
newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
newProcess.Start();
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) for `UseShellExecute` state:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use the operating system shell to start the process.

In this case, you do want that.